# drools xls error Failed to open Excel stream, please check that the content is xls97 format

Tags: excel, linux, apache-poi, window, drools

I am getting below error when I am trying the below line.

```
VerifierBuilder vBuilder = VerifierBuilderFactory.newVerifierBuilder();
Verifier verifier = vBuilder.newVerifier();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(multipartExcel.getInputStream());
DecisionTableConfiguration dtconf = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
dtconf.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
verifier.addResourcesToVerify(ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(reader), ResourceType.DTABLE, dtconf);
```

The same code is working fine in my windows pc. But when I deploy as a docker into a linux vm I am getting this error. I tried the size of file received in both servers, its same.

```
equest processing failed; nested exception is org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: Failed to open Excel stream, please check that the content is xls97 format.] with root cause

java.io.IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:258) ~[poi-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:221) ~[poi-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile(ExcelParser.java:101) ~[drools-decisiontables-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.parseResource(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:136) ~[drools-decisiontables-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:120) ~[drools-decisiontables-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:93) ~[drools-decisiontables-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.compileResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:74) ~[drools-decisiontables-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromResource(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:42) ~[drools-decisiontables-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableFactory.loadFromResource(DecisionTableFactory.java:35) ~[drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.decisionTableToPackageDescr(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:412) ~[drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addPackageFromDecisionTable(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:381) ~[drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addKnowledgeResource(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:749) ~[drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.verifier.builder.VerifierPackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(VerifierPackageBuilder.java:40) ~[drools-verifier-drl-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at org.drools.verifier.builder.VerifierImpl.addResourcesToVerify(VerifierImpl.java:199) ~[drools-verifier-drl-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
        at RuleService.validateRule(RuleService.java:272) ~[rule-1.0.0.jar:na]
        at RuleService.saveRule(RuleService.java:87) ~[rule-1.0.0.jar:na]
        at RuleController.createRule(RuleController.java:70) ~[rule-1.0.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved it. Posting here, as if this help others.

Instead of passing reader, I 've saved the multipart into a file and passed the file into the ResourceFactory. like below

```
verifier.addResourcesToVerify(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(downloadedFile), ruleResourceType, dtconf);
```